# Testing multiple routes causes Jest mocked function to be undefined

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, ts-jest

I would like to know the best way to test multiple routes in expressJS with jest.

My current problem is when I try testing multiple routes that uses same mocked function, the last route throws an undefined error.

Here's the context in code.

app.ts

```
import * as express from "express";
import controllerOne from "./controllers/one";
import controllerTwo from "./controllers/two";

const app = express();

app.use("/one", controllerOne);
app.use("/two", controllerTwo);

export default app;
```

controllers/one.ts

```
import getDbConnection from "../db";
import * as express from "express";

const router = express.Router();

const db = getDbConnection();

router.get("/", async (_, res) => {
  const sql = "SELECT * from table";

  const result = await db.query(sql);

  res.status(200).json(result);
});

export default router;
```

controllers/two.ts

```
import getDbConnection from "../db";
import * as express from "express";

const router = express.Router();

const db = getDbConnection();

router.get("/", async (_, res) => {
  const sql = "SELECT * from table";

  const result = await db.query(sql);

  res.status(200).json(result);
});

export default router;
```

tests/one.ts

```
import * as request from "supertest";
import { mocked } from "ts-jest/utils";
import db from "../db";

jest.mock("../db");

const mockedDB = mocked(db);

const data = ["data"];

describe("Controller One", () => {
  afterAll(() => {
    jest.restoreAllMocks();
    jest.resetModules();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    const mockedQueryFn = {
      query: jest.fn().mockResolvedValueOnce(data),
    };

    mockedDB.mockReturnValueOnce(mockedQueryFn);
  });

  it("should retrieve one", async () => {
    const mod = require("../src/app");
    const app = (mod as any).default;

    await request(app)
      .get("/one")
      .expect(200)
      .expect(function (res) {
        expect(res.body).toEqual(data);
      });
  });
});
```

tests/two.ts

```
import * as request from "supertest";
import { mocked } from "ts-jest/utils";
import db from "../db";

jest.mock("../db");

const mockedDB = mocked(db);

const data = ["data"];

describe("Controller One", () => {
  afterAll(() => {
    jest.restoreAllMocks();
    jest.resetModules();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    const mockedQueryFn = {
      query: jest.fn().mockResolvedValueOnce(data),
    };

    mockedDB.mockReturnValueOnce(mockedQueryFn);
  });

  it("should retrieve one", async () => {
    const mod = require("../src/app");
    const app = (mod as any).default;

    await request(app)
      .get("/two")
      .expect(200)
      .expect(function (res) {
        expect(res.body).toEqual(data);
      });
  });
});
```

Now my problem is if I run the test, test/one.ts would pass test/two.ts would fail with the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined` referencing this line `const result = await db.query(sql)`

When I switch up the controller imports

```
import controllerTwo from "./controllers/two";
import controllerOne from "./controllers/one";
```

then `test/two.ts` passes and `test/one.ts` fails with same error.
I would like to also mention that with/without reseting jest mock, I get same result.

Answer (score 0):

It may have to do with the fact that you’re not calling done at the end of your test. Inside the expect part of the test, call `done()`. You also need to change the callback so that it like this:

```
it("should retrieve one", async (done) => {
```